# Reading from SQS - optimizing for parallelism?

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-sqs

I have an SQS queue that posts file notifications from SNS. I have an app that reads these files and does some work on them.

It seems that no matter how many simultaneous threads I run I can only consume at a fixed rate. As a result the app maxes out the consumer rate and begins to lag during times of higher traffic.

It doesn't appear to be a limitation on the system - there are numerous cores with low to no load while this is running.

Each thread is sending a `ReceiveMessageRequest` with the max (10) messages and a 60 second timeout.

Questions:

- is there a better way to receive messages? Maybe one listener and multiple processors pulling from a shared queue?
- is there a known limit per application? Would it help to distribute this work among multiple instances or even hosts?
- some other strategy for keeping pace with SQS?

Comment: *"I can only consume at a fixed rate."*  What's the rate you're achieving?  Is this a FIFO queue?